# Multiple app icons being installed when using Flavors and multiple manifest files

Tags: android, android-manifest, intentfilter

I currently have a project that needs to contain two different forms of codebase, legacy and an updated version of the application. I am using Flavors for this, but am running into an issue where two app icons are being installed. The reason is because both the legacy codebase and the updated codebase have their own manifest.xml, and inside the manifest are declarations for identifying the Main launch class and their relative app icon.

```
 <!-- legacy code manifest -->
    <activity
        android:name="legacy.activity.RegistrationActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/CustomAppTheme"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <!-- updated code manifest -->
    <activity
        android:name="updated.activity.RegistrationActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/CustomAppTheme"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

How can I get around this? If I remove the intent-filter from the updated code base, which is the Main codebase, the Flavor will not install two icons. However, I am unable to run the Main codebase because I have not declared an entry point in my Manifest. And conversely, if I remove the intent-filter from the Flavor and keep it in my Main codebase, the Flavor code will not run. The two RegistrationActivity classes are different, just with the same name. The Legacy code does not really share much of the updated codebase. Any suggestions other than separate into different projects?

Some have requested my setup with Flavors in gradle, here is snapshot of it.

```
productFlavors {
    standard {
        applicationId 'updated.android.example'
        manifestPlaceholders = [package_name: "updated.android.example", primary_lang: "en"]
        signingConfig signingConfigs.keystore
    }
    legacyTest {
        applicationId 'legacy.android.example.debug'
        manifestPlaceholders = [package_name: "legacy.android.example.debug",
                                target      : "Test", primary_lang: "en"]
        signingConfig signingConfigs.keystore
    }
    legacyProd {
        applicationId 'legacy.android.example.prod'
        manifestPlaceholders = [package_name: "legacy.android.example.prod",
                                target      : "Prod", primary_lang: "en"]
        signingConfig signingConfigs.keystore
    }
```

Comment: can you share your gradle file as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
```

says that you have a launching activity. Set them to a default activity setting(this is just "another activity", create a third class that is the launcher-class. This class will automatically redirect to one of the two other activities based on whatever specifications you may have, such as API level or brand. Any specifications you have as to which to launch, set them and the user will not know there is a handling activity.

When you have two launcher activities, they show as two applications. This is probably because the system cannot determine what to redirect to automatically. So there are two depending on what to launch.

> How can I get around this? If I remove the intent-filter from the updated code base, which is the Main codebase,

Don't remove it. Change it. E.g.:

```
       <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.yourpackage.name.CLASSNAME" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
```

Comment: What about the main `AndroidManifest`. What should I put in it?

Answer (score 1):

You need separate `<activity android:name="legacy.activity.RegistrationActivity"` and `<activity android:name="updated.activity.RegistrationActivity"` you two manifests, one for each flavor.

eg.:

`src/main/AndroidManifest.xml` (with everything except: *.activity.RegistrationActivity)
`src/legacy/AndroidManifest.xml` (with legacy.activity.RegistrationActivity)
`src/updated/AndroidManifest.xml` (with updated.activity.RegistrationActivity)

Comment: What about the main `AndroidManifest`. What should I put in it?